# sending data to server continuously in android

Tags: android, job-scheduling, android-handler

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
TextView tvIsConnected;
EditText etName,etCountry,etTwitter;
Button btnPost;

Person person;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get reference to the views
    tvIsConnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIsConnected);
    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etCountry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCountry);
    etTwitter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTwitter);
    btnPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPost);

    // check if you are connected or not
    if(isConnected()){
        tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
        tvIsConnected.setText("You are conncted");
    }
    else{
        tvIsConnected.setText("You are NOT conncted");
    }

    // add click listener to Button "POST"
    btnPost.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public static String POST(String url, Person person){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = "";

        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.accumulate("name", person.getName());
        jsonObject.accumulate("country", person.getCountry());
        jsonObject.accumulate("twitter", person.getTwitter());

        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();

        // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib
        // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    // 11. return result
    return result;
}

public boolean isConnected(){
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnPost:
            if(!validate())
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter some data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
            new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet");
            break;
    }

}
private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        person = new Person();
        person.setName(etName.getText().toString());
        person.setCountry(etCountry.getText().toString());
        person.setTwitter(etTwitter.getText().toString());

        return POST(urls[0],person);
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private boolean validate(){
    if(etName.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else if(etCountry.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else if(etTwitter.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```

}

This is the code i am working with. In this code i send three text to the server from android. All i want to do is to give the inputs in android and it will post in the server in every 5 min. How can i do do it with handler thread?

Comment: Use Timer for sending data in every 5 min.

Comment: is your problem solved, or you tried with another approach

Answer (score 0):

Use Timer task to do that job

```
Timer timerObj = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTaskObj = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
       //perform your action here
    }
};
timerObj.schedule(timerTaskObj, 5000, 15000);
```

you can give delay and period according to your need.below is method description [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29)

schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
 Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // add your code here     or call your method here
        }
    };
    Handler handler = new Handler();
```

In oncreate call this

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5 * 60 * 1000);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) just like [anddevmanu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43868173/3302373) explained, but it's long running task and implementing it in the activity is not a good idea. Use [Background Service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) for it.

Comment: Thanks sammie , that depends on requirement and usage.